# Copying columns from an array to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still beginning on VBA and wanted to ask how to copy data from cells that are not empty in a specific array to another array. So I have this table that I named "Candidatures" (it doesn't start on row 1) and I want to copy only the cells that contain data from it  and copy it to another worksheet. Here's what I got so far :

```
Dim arrCandidatures() As Variant
arrCandidatures = Range("Candidatures").Value

Dim iCol As Long
Dim iRow As Long

   iMaxRow = 250

For iCol = 1 To 6 'these are the columns i want to copy from "Candidatures"
    For iRow = 1 To iMaxRow
        With Worksheets(CopierColler).Array(arrCandidatures).Columns(iCol)
            If .Value = "" Then
            Else: .Copy Destination:=Worksheets("RawData").Cells(D2, I10)
            End If
        End With

    Next iRow
Next iCol
```

Any suggestions ?

Jonathan

Comment: where does this fail? What error is shown?

Comment: error is in this line of code With Worksheets(CopierColler).Array(arrCandidatures).Columns(iCol) i can't manage to select the table in which I want columns 1 to 6 selected

Comment: Is it an excel table, or just a group of cells?

Comment: Its a group of cells, which probably means I can't use Columns and rows?

Comment: Well then remove the array part. Worksheet.columns should work just fine. No idea why you put the Array part in between there.

Comment: If I remove the array part, won't it just copy the columns 1 to 6 of the whole sheet, which contains other data that I don't want copied ?

Comment: Well then you need to specify those columns so instead of 1 to 6 perhaps 12 to 18...

Comment: Ok I'll try that thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems a little flawed because you say that you wish to copy only cells which aren't blank. Normally, one would copy rows which aren't blank but including blank cells within the chosen rows. Therefore I suggest this approach: first copy everything and then remove the rows you don't want to keep. The following code would copy everything.

```
Private Sub CopyPasteRange()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant

    With Range("Candidatures")
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(0, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count - 1, 6))
    End With

    Debug.Print Rng.Address, Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count
    Arr = Rng.Value
    Debug.Print Lbound(Arr,1), Lbound(Arr, 2), Ubound(Arr,1), Ubound(Arr,2)
    Debug.Print Worksheets("RawData").Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Address
    Worksheets("RawData").Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(Arr, 1), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
End Sub
```

Note that the destination cell(2,1) is A2, meaning row 2, column 1. This is the top left cell of the entire range being copied and you can change it to meet your requirements.

When you loop through the new rows in "RawData" remember to do so from bottom to top so that you can delete the row that doesn't meet your requirements for being kept.

Note: I'm rather surprised at the code `.Range(.Cells(0, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count - 1, 6))`. `Cells(0, 1)` which would normally throw an error. It doesn't in this case because it refers to a named range. I tested and it works correctly. However, you say you have a table. I'm not familiar with tables because I learned Excel before they were introduced. Anyway, if this line of code gives you any problem it would be because there is no row 0 in Excel. The "normal" way of constructing this line of code would be `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6))` but when I tried that it gave me the wrong range. With the zero it picks up the correct data from a named range.

Comment: I see what you mean, what I want my code to do is to copy the filled cells until it finds an empty one, because in my particular case, an empty cell indicates the end of the data (I however defined my "candidatures" table bigger, and therefore contains an amount of empty rows under the filled ones that would need to be deleted). 
I tried this but the I get an error '9' message and the last line of the code is the problem apparently.

Comment: Why do you need "Candidatures" to be a table? Once you use VBA the worksheet is the dominant unit. Every address in a table must be converted to its equivalent on the sheet. In consequence your problems could be much smaller if you could just use the sheet as a table.

Comment: In the last line, the source and target ranges must be identical in size. `Rng` is the source, and the resized cell on "RawData" is the target. I have added code to the above solution to examine these two ranges. You can check if `Rng` picks the correct area from which to copy the data and how the size of the two ranges differs. The output of `Debug.Print` is to the VB Editor's Immediate Window.

Comment: Oooh YES !! I'll just separate my candidates table in a single worksheet ! Thanks a lot for you help, I appreciate it !! :D